# Reading TIFF file using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, arcgis-pro, setnull

I have trouble when I try to set null some value, when I try this code, it didn't do anything or exporting any file. I run this code on Python ArcGIS Pro and when I import the ArcPy and os it seems ok.

```
import arcpy
import os
#inputcloudmask
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\aa\TUGAS AKHIR\VNP46\2018\1 Juni 2018\QF Cloud Mask"

path = "E:\aa\TUGAS AKHIR\VNP46\2018\1 Juni 2018\QF Cloud Mask"

raw_name = os.listdir(path)
rname: str
outname = []
for rname in raw_name:
    portion = os.path.splitext(rname)
    temp_name = 'filter' + portion[0] + '.TIF'
    outname.append(temp_name)

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("QF*","TIF")
i = 0
for raster in rasters:
    Oname = outname[i]
    i = i + 1
    outSetNull = arcpy.sa.SetNull(raster, 1, "VALUE <> 32 And VALUE <> 34 And VALUE <> 36 And VALUE <> 42 And VALUE <> 48 And VALUE <> 50 And VALUE <> 52 And VALUE <> 58 And VALUE <> 1056 And VALUE <> 1058 And VALUE <> 1060 And VALUE <> 1066 And VALUE <> 1072 And VALUE <> 1074 And VALUE <> 1076 And VALUE <> 1082")
    on = "E:/aa/TUGAS AKHIR/VNP46/2018/1 Juni 2018\output" + Oname
    outSetNull.save(on)
    print(raster + "---->" + Oname)
```

This is the file in my path (E:\aa\TUGAS AKHIR\VNP46\2018\1 Juni 2018\QF Cloud Mask)

[image: file in my path]

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an `r` before each string containing the absolute path to the file/directory. Without the `r`, Python interprets several escape sequences such as `\t`, `\n` and in your case, `\a`.

For example, run this as an excercise:

```py
>>> print("\a")  # doesn't print anything

>>> print(r"\a")  # prints the literal string
\a
```

With your paths, there is also a difference:

```py
>>> print("E:\aa\TUGAS AKHIR\VNP46\2018\1 Juni 2018\QF Cloud Mask")
E:a\TUGAS AKHIR\VNP468 Juni 2018\QF Cloud Mask
>>> print(r"E:\aa\TUGAS AKHIR\VNP46\2018\1 Juni 2018\QF Cloud Mask")
E:\aa\TUGAS AKHIR\VNP46\2018\1 Juni 2018\QF Cloud Mask
```

Furthermore, I would strongly recommend avoiding whitespaces in paths as they can cause other type of issues.